# How to create item objects from reading a text file?

Tags: java

I'm trying to read data from a text file and create Item Objects with it.
Item Objects have fields  String title, String formatt, boolean onLoan, String loanedTo and String dateLoaned. In my save()method, I print every object to a text file in a new line and the fields are seperated by "$" (dollar sign). How can I read the text file line by line and create a new object from each line and add it to an array.

TextFile Example:

StarWars$DVD$false$null$null

Aliens$Bluray$true$John$Monday

```
public void save() {
    String[] array2 = listForSave();
    PrintWriter printer = null;

      try {
          printer = new PrintWriter(file);

            for (String o : array2) {
            printer.println(o);
            }
            printer.close();
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
public void open(){
    try{

    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        stringBuffer.append(line);
        stringBuffer.append("\n");
    }
    fileReader.close();
    System.out.println("Contents of file:");
    System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());

    }catch ( IOException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Thanks everyone. Here's my final code:

```
public void open(){
    try{

    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    String line;
    String[] strings;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        strings = line.split("\\$");
        String title = strings[0];
         String format = strings[1];
         boolean onLoan = Boolean.parseBoolean(strings[2]);
         String loanedTo = strings[3];
         String dateLoaned = strings[4];

         MediaItem superItem = new MediaItem(title,format, onLoan,loanedTo,dateLoaned);
         items.add(superItem);

    }
    fileReader.close();


    }catch ( IOException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String line = // input line e.g. "Aliens$Bluray$true$John$Monday"
String[] strings = line.split("\\$"); // use regex matching "$" to split
String title = strings[0];
String formatt = strings[1];
boolean onLoan = Boolean.parseBoolean(strings[2]);
String loanedTo = strings[3];
String dateLoaned = strings[4];
// TODO: create object from those values
```

Maybe you need to handle `null` differently (in case you want the String `"null"` to be converted to `null`); note that you can't distinguish if `null` or `"null"` was saved.

This function converts `"null"` to `null` and returns the same string otherwise:

```
String convert(String s) {
    return s.equals("null") ? null : s;
}
```

#### Reading the objects to an array

Since you don't know the number of elements before reading *all* lines, you have to work around that:

1. Write the number of objects in the file as first line, which would allow you to create the array before reading the first object. (Use `Integer.parseInt(String)` to convert the first line to int):

   ```
   public void save() {
       String[] array2 = listForSave();
       PrintWriter printer = null;

         try {
             printer = new PrintWriter(file);
             printer.println(array2.length);
               for (String o : array2) {
                   printer.println(o);
               }
               printer.close();
           } catch ( IOException e ) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

   }
   public void open(){
       try{

       FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
       BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
       StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
       int arraySize = Integer.parseInt(stringBuffer.readLine());
       Object[] array = new Object[arraySize];
       int index = 0;
       String line;
       while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
           // split line and create Object (see above)
           Object o = // ...
           array[index++] = o;
       }
       //...
       }catch ( IOException e ) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       //...
   }
   ```

   or
2. Use a `Collection`, e.g. `ArrayList` to store the objects and use [`List.toArray(T[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray-T:A-) to get an array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my text file can be changed and does may not always contain the same data. How can I use String line =... to make it read everyline automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this to "parse" every line of your file

```
String[] result = "StarWars$DVD$false$null$null".split("\\$");
for (int i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
     String field = result[i]
     ... put the strings in your object ...  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

quick and dirty solution might be...

```
public void open(){
    try{
    ArrayList<Item> list = new ArrayList<Item>(); //Array of your ItemObject

    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
      Item itm = new Item(); //New Item Object 
      String [] splitLine = line.split("\\$");

      item.title = splitLine[0];
      item.format = splitLine[1];
      item.onLoan = Boolean.parseBoolean(splitLine[2]);
      item.loanedTo = splitLine[3];
      item.dateLoaned = splitLine[4];

      list.add(itm);

      stringBuffer.append(line);
      stringBuffer.append("\n");
    }
    fileReader.close();
    System.out.println("Contents of file:");
    System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());

    }catch ( IOException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But this is won't scale if you need to re-arrange or add new fields.