# How to read a string of characters from a text file until a certain character, print them in the console, then continue?

Tags: java

i have a question. I have a text file with some names and numbers arranged like this :

Cheese;10;12

Borat;99;55

I want to read the chars and integers from the file until the ";" symbol, println them, then continue, read the next one, println etc. Like this :

Cheese -> println , 10-> println, 99 -> println , and on to the next line and continue.

I tried using :

```
BufferedReader flux_in = new BufferedReader (
                         new InputStreamReader (
                         new FileInputStream ("D:\\test.txt")));

while ((line = flux_in.readLine())!=null && 
line.contains(terminator)==true)
{
    text = line;
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(text));   
}
```

But it reads the entire line, doesn`t stop at the ";" symbol. Setting the 'contains' condition to false does not read the line at all.

EDIT : Partially solved, i managed to write this code :

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
//  while ((line = flux_in.readLine())!=null)

        int c;
        String terminator_char = ";";
        while((c = flux_in.read()) != -1) {
        {
         char character = (char) c;
             if (String.valueOf(character).contains(terminator_char)==false)
              {
    //       System.out.println(String.valueOf(character) + " : Char");
                 sb.append(character); 
              }
              else 
              {
                  continue;
              }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(sb) );
```

Which returns a new string formed out of the characters from the read one, but without the ";". Still need a way to make it stop on the first ";", println the string and continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Read the characters from file 1 by 1
2. Delete the 'contains' condition
3. Use a stringBuilder() to build yourself the strings 1 by 1
4. Each stringBuilder stops when facing a ';' (say you use an if clause)

I didn't test it because I'm on my phone. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, i was thinking about the same thing , reading the string char  by char, stopping at the ';'  ,build a new string then print it, continue and so on an so forth. Didn`t know about the stringbuilder class, it should help.

Comment: Please let me know if you solve the problem and then mark the question as solved.

Comment: Partially solved . I managed to write the code  in the first post (could not properly format it in the comment, so i edited the first post). I returns a string formed out of the text on one line, but without the symbol ";".

Comment: Instead of BufferedReader, use Scanner
Scanner scanner = new Scanner("D:\\test.txt");

And use scanner.next() that will read your next character.
scanner.nextLine() reads until end of line

Comment: Yup , that should solve it according to this documentation : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html . Seems it`s exactly what i need. Will report back in 5 minutes, thanks a lot for all the fast replys.

Comment: Contains simply returns true and the Reading goes on. 
Try if(scanner.next().equals(terminator)) instead of your if clause

Remember that Java is not pass-by-value. So you cannot compare two strings using '=='. Compare them using string1.equals(string2)

Comment: Such a simple solution, didn`t even need the if as a matter of fact. Just this, a custom delimiter and the hasNext method :  Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("D:\\test.txt"));
  
  scan.useDelimiter(";");
  System.out.println("Delimiter:" + scan.delimiter());
  
  while (scan.hasNext()) {
   System.out.println(scan.next());
  }
  
  scan.close();

Comment: I`ll mark this as solved and add the solution, thanks for the input. One last question, how to i tag code in comments so it looks proper? (new to the site, and the instructions regarding using '  ' before and after the code don`t seem to do anything.

Comment: Glad you did it. Also, give check my comment as the solver, please. It will help my reputation. And for the code tag, you can write code in comments, but block-formatting is reserved for questions and answers

Comment: Checked as solved. Thanks a lot again. Also found another method for doing it, BufferedReader has a method called split("delimitator") that you can use to split a string via a specified delimitator and then put the resulting streams into an array of strings. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29975900/how-to-create-item-objects-from-reading-a-text-file?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

This simple code does the trick, thanks to Stefan Vasilica for the ideea :

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("D:\\testfile.txt"));
    // Printing the delimiter used
    scan.useDelimiter(";");
    System.out.println("Delimiter:" + scan.delimiter());
    // Printing the tokenized Strings
    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(scan.next());
    }
    // closing the scanner stream
    scan.close();
```